# Kivy store Canvas contents in StringIO

Tags: android, canvas, kivy

I´m testing following paint app example (https://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/firstwidget.html):

```
from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):

  def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    color = (random(), random(), random())
    with self.canvas:
        Color(*color)
        d = 30.
        Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d))
        touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))

  def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]


class MyPaintApp(App):

 def build(self):
    parent = Widget()
    self.painter = MyPaintWidget()
    clearbtn = Button(text='Clear')
    clearbtn.bind(on_release=self.clear_canvas)
    parent.add_widget(self.painter)
    parent.add_widget(clearbtn)
    return parent

 def clear_canvas(self, obj):
    self.painter.export_to_png("testcanvas.png") #store canvas in a png file 
    self.painter.canvas.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   MyPaintApp().run()
```

The example works fine. I´m trying to store the the contents I draw in the canvas to a file, but when I open the file it is completely black and there are no contents. I want to store the canvas contents to a Python StringIO in order to sent them through a websocket. First I´m trying to store the canvas contents to a file. Is there a way to store the canvas image to a StringIO in order to do, afterwards, on backend (websocket server) side:

img_array = np.asarray(bytearray(img_stream.read()), dtype=np.uint8)

?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`export_to_png()`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.export_to_png), which will do exactly what the function name says. To send it just open that file and either send it in parts, or whole.

Better alternative, instead of `canvas` of any widget use [`StencilView`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.stencilview.html), which will behave as a canvas "widget", therefore you can export to png easily whole content of a widget and no additional and unnecessary stuff will be saved with that(other widgets for example).

Black png sometimes happens, there are issues such as this one on [iOS](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/3607), but mostly it works. At least with master branch.